# Handling multiple clicks on uwp button

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, uwp

I would like to have a different method called depending on the number of time I click on a button, from 1 to 5, on an UWP application.
Is it possible ? How ?

Answer (score 0):

I've used something like this in my windows forms application, maybe it will help. This switch operation was inside  button click event.

```
int clickCounter = 0;

        switch (clickCounter)
        {
            case 1:
                {

                }
                break;
            case 2:
                {

                }
                break;
        }
```

Comment: Yes but I would like to handle it as the "Double_tab". If the user tap or click 5 times in a short period, calling a specific method

Comment: So why can't you just make simple click counter ?

Comment: Because if the user do a simple click, I load another page

Comment: Use john.kernel's code and run `DispatcherTimer` on click. When it fires check click count.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one or two clicks is built-in:

```
var b = new Button();
b.Tapped += (s, e) => {  /* TODO */ };
b.DoubleTapped += (s, e) => {  /* TODO */ };
```

But if you want three clicks, say, you need `john.kernel`'s solution (above). Of course, you would use only Tapped to track, then some kind of timing threshold, too. Otherwise they could tap twice in 5 minutes and John's code would fire.

> I don't mind interjecting that a triple-click is lame. Not discoverable. But, hey, I don't know your app or your user base, do I? So, you do what you think is right. You are the developer.

Best of luck!

Comment: This is supposed to be a hidden button, a demand from the client. I don't think this is the best solution but they will be able to test now.
The clent's need change and now I only need 1 button which react to 5 taps  only. My question is not revelant now, I do not need any help anymore. Thanks both of you